# how to find that whether the file exist or not using c#

Tags: c#, .net

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog FldrBrowseDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FldrBrowseDlg.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        DialogResult DigRslt = FldrBrowseDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (DigRslt.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            textBox1.Text = FldrBrowseDlg.SelectedPath;
            Environment.SpecialFolder rootfolder = FldrBrowseDlg.RootFolder;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(textBox1.Text);
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*doc.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (FileInfo fl in files)
        {
            string s1 = fl.ToString();
            string name = s1.Substring(0, 28);
            string kyrname = name + ".txt";
            if (File.Exists(textBox1.Text+"*/"+kyrname))
            {
                label1.Text = "have kyrplus";
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(name);
            }
```

I want to search the file but it is not taking the the path that I am giving in `File.Exixts()` function what to do?

Comment: File.Exists works correctly. So does FileInfo.Exists. If they return `false` is because the file path is wrong or the file simply doesn't exist. Also, instead of string processing to find a file's folder or filename, use FileInfo's and Path's methods to return the folder, filename without folder or extension, extension, etc. If you want to create a new path, use `Path.Combine`

Comment: Are you getting an error? `*` or `/` aren't allowed in filenames. What are you trying to do? Find if a file exists or perform a wildcard search? Are you trying to find to perform a recursive search for the file names?

Comment: i  m nt getting any error

Comment: i had browse the file, the path is in text box , but i want to search the file in the subfolder of the path  and i dont knw the name of subfolder so what i have to write in File.Exists()??

Comment: Nothing. `File.Exists` checks for existence, it doesn't *search*. You already used the method that *searches*, it's `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` or `Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: i want that only, i want to knw wether the file exist in the sub folder or not if not it will show which file dont exist in subflder

Comment: That's searching, not checking for existence.

Comment: got it thanx for guidance

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because your path is not correct.

```
File.Exists(textBox1.Text+"*/"+kyrname)
```

You need to check what is the value in your `textBox1.Text` and then you can concatenate the value with `"*/"` and `.txt`. It doesnt look to me as a valid path.

**EDIT:**

You can try like this if you are looking for a file in all the subdirectory

```
var file = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text, kyrname, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
if (file == null)
{
    // File does not exist
}
```

Comment: i had browse the file, the path is in text box , but i want to search the file in the subfolder of the path and i dont knw the name of subfolder so what i have to write in File.Exists()??

Comment: @SaguphaParween:- If you are not sure about which subfolder it is in then you can search the file in subdirectory. Check the updated answer,

Comment: Calling `Any()` would be preferable to `FirstOrDefault` and the null check.